# Get fields values of a form within asp.net web forms application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, web

I'm beginner in `Asp.Net Web Forms`. I have this problem:

I added a login form to my page like this

```
 <form  runat="server" action="Default/Login" method="post">
   <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="134px" TextLayout="TextOnTop" Width="377px">
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" style="height:134px;width:377px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#990000;font-size:0.9em;font-weight:bold;">Se connecter</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Nom d&#39;utilisateur&nbsp;:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Size="0.8em" Font-Names="user"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Un nom d'utilisateur est requis." ToolTip="Un nom d'utilisateur est requis." ValidationGroup="Login1" ForeColor="Red">Un nom d'utilisateur est requis</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Mot de passe&nbsp;:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Font-Size="0.8em" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Un mot de passe est requis." ToolTip="Un mot de passe est requis." ValidationGroup="Login1" ForeColor="Red">Un mot de passe est requis</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Mémoriser le mot de passe." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Button  runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" Text="Se connecter"   />
                                      </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" />
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Login>
    </form>
```

And an action in the code Behind :

```
public void Login() { }
```

but i got this error :

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, has been renamed or is temporarily unavailable.
```

1. What is the reasons of this error?
2. How can i retrieve the values of the form's fields in the code behind ( i'm used to do this in Asp.net mvc but it seems more difficult here)?

Comment: In the forms action you have place `Default/Login` - apparently can not find that page/translation to page.

Comment: How can i fix it to redirect to the method `Login` in the code Behind of the page `Default.aspx`?

Comment: You should really invest some time reading about how to use the login control and then come back with any further questions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d51ttbhx(v=vs.85).aspx